# Android Jetpack Compose Navigation Recomposition Multiple times

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use jetpack compose. But when I tried to use jetpack compose navigation, I found that navigated screen is recomposed multiple times. Following is my code snippet.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DemoAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "First") {
                    composable("First") {
                        Log.e("TAG", "First Screen")
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                            Button(onClick = {
                                navController.navigate("Second")
                            }) {
                                Text(text = "Second Screen")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    composable("Second") {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Second Screen")
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my log,

2023-09-25 14:34:09.672 19634-19634 TAG                     com.example.demoapp                 =>  First Screen

2023-09-25 14:34:09.678 19634-19634 TAG                     com.example.demoapp                 =>  Second Screen

2023-09-25 14:34:09.701 19634-19634 TAG                     com.example.demoapp                 =>  First Screen

2023-09-25 14:34:09.706 19634-19634 TAG                     com.example.demoapp                 =>  Second Screen

2023-09-25 14:34:10.415 19634-19634 TAG                     com.example.demoapp                 =>  Second Screen

2023-09-25 14:34:10.434 19634-19634 TAG                     com.example.demoapp                 =>  Second Screen

I think it should build one time for the navigation.

Comment: it is make sense, if your leave from `Page1` to `Page2`, `Page1` is close and replace with `Page2`. nothing is wrong. what are you needs?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the recomposition of the "First" screen when navigating back from the "Second" screen, you can use the rememberSaveable function to retain the state of the "First" composable. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DemoAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "First") {
                    composable("First") {
                        Log.e("TAG", "First Screen")
                        val firstScreenData = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                            Button(onClick = {
                                navController.navigate("Second")
                            }) {
                                Text(text = "Second Screen")
                            }

                            Text(text = "First Screen Data: ${firstScreenData.value}")
                        }
                    }

                    composable("Second") {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Second Screen")
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is that second screen is recomposing when navigating from the first screen. As you can see in my log, "Second Screen" is showing multiple times when user click button.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225987040?pli=1 It is marked as won't fix

I faced the exact same issue